# how to establish video conference feature in java web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jmf, video-conferencing

I was developing an web application in Java. In that application I have a requirement to develop video conference feature for allowing client to have video chat with company representative. I have done a little research and found Java Media Framework....
Are there any better solutions for developing web based video conferencing using java J2EE...

Comment: Why bother implementing from the scratch ? You can provide some skype link and everyone is familiar already with that.

Comment: it's company project bro ...so i have implement from scratch...

Comment: @Rajasekhar Reddy, that's your brother?

Answer (score 9):

You are on right track.

**JMF** is the best for video conferencing.

**JMF** does provide the basic building blocks for a conferencing application to transmit and receive media over **RTP**. It is possible to build fully- featured standard-based conferencing solutions on **JMF** if you combine it with conferencing protocols like **H.323.**

**Ref URL :** http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/faq-jmf-137005.html#jmf2-conferencing

Actually there are mainly **2 file** from which you can communicate with java jmf plugin.

**[AVTransmit2.java](http://bluejimp.com/jitsi/libjitsi/javadoc/org/jitsi/examples/AVTransmit2.html)** works as a data capturer from your own webcam and transmit the data to the peer's IP address.

**[AVReceive2.java](http://bluejimp.com/jitsi/libjitsi/javadoc/org/jitsi/examples/AVReceive2.html)** works as a data receiver from your remote peer and play the data by java jmf plugin.

Below is the Video Conferencing project, which might be helpful to you.

http://matrixsust.blogspot.in/2013/07/video-conferencing-project-in-java.html